# Shall i make mobile version of my website indexed by search engines?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, mobile

I have a website with a separate version for mobile and smart phones but the user cannot open the mobile version from Desktop and vise versa the Desktop version cannot opened from Mobile device(s).

Shall i make both version and specially the mobile version indexed by search engines?

Comment: Do they share the same content?

Comment: Yes, but i separate them by adding: Link Rel="canonical" in mobile pages.

Comment: Content used by users should always be crawlable unless there is sensitive data. Using canonical is one way of fixing the problem.

Comment: Sorry but after reviewing your question this has been asked several times on Pro Webmasters in various forms. You can find a whole bunch of questions and answers regarding [tackling duplicate content](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-content) as well as [related mobile duplicates](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=mobile+duplicate+content).